# products below a specific price in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode

I have a Woocommerce store with more than 1000 products. I would like that all products which have a price below 500 should be shown on a separate page, so I can tag that Page in my menu.
Is there a shortcode that i can use to display {atleast first 4 products} the same on a block on the home page?

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
add_shortcode( 'products_below_500', 'products_below_500_shortcode' );


function products_below_500_shortcode() {


$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key' => '_price',
        'value' => 500,
        'compare' => '<'
     )
  ),
  'fields' => 'ids',
 );

  $product_ids = get_posts( $args ); 
  $product_ids = implode( ",", $product_ids );
  return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids' columns= 4 ]");
}
```

Usage : [products_below_500]  // on page you want to use